# How did prophet suleiman order jinn to build images?

Tags: quran, shirk, prophets

I read in origin of shirk that 5th generation of prophet Adam started image worship. Subsequently Prophet Noah was sent as messenger to stop image worship.

Since statue building/ image making is forbidden in Islam. how did suleiman order building of statues/images?

> They made for him whatever he desired of sanctuaries, **statues** basins as large as reservoirs, and cooking pots fixed ˹into the ground˺. ˹We ordered:˺ “Work gratefully, O  family of David!” ˹Only˺ a few of My servants are ˹truly˺ grateful.

Quran 34:13.

Additionally I heard from lectures that all Prophets are innocent of shirk.

Comment: That is irrelevant. Your query is addressed in the answer to that question. Making images was permissible, worshiping them is forbidden \ shirk and nowhere does it state that the images were made for worship.

Comment: Sorry I read the answer now